# Is it safe to type the UserId into the local stroge

Tags: local-storage, userid

I want to store the UserId in localStroge is it safe?if not, how do you suggest a way?
I need a place to store tokens like userId.how safe is it to store in local stroge?
I thought about using cookies, but if the user blocks cookies, then the system crashes

Comment: This might be relevant: [Should I obscure database primary keys (IDs) in application front end?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56357/should-i-obscure-database-primary-keys-ids-in-application-front-end)